# In Android Application I am opening a video from URL but Can't open the Video error is showing but same Video opening when placed in raw asset

Tags: android, android-studio

How to open the Video from URL and how to check whether the video is opened or not
I tried to play a video from this code by passing a Video Url

```
 VideoView videoView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_view_1);
 videoView.setVideoPath(videoItem.videoUrl);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();

                float videoRatio= mp.getVideoWidth()/(float)mp.getVideoHeight();
                float screenRatio=videoView.getWidth() /(float) videoView.getHeight();

                float scale=videoRatio/ screenRatio;
                if(scale<1f){
                    videoView.setScaleX(scale);
                }else{
                    videoView.setScaleY(1f/scale);
                }
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try to use "setVideoURI" instead of "setVideoPath"

Comment: You can also try the Exoplayer to play video from URL

Comment: I tried setVideoURI also it is also not working

Comment: I will try ExoPlayer could you share any references if you know @gpuser

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer